# Passing GIT_COMMIT when promoting Jenkins Jobs

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have a Jenkins CI system that has two jobs. Job number one is a standard Git Plugin job that runs whenever there is something pushed to master. Successes in can be promoted to job number two. Job number two is pretty much a deploy script that requires the GIT_COMMIT from job number one. I have checked "Pass-through Git Commit that was built." However, in job number two, when I echo GIT_COMMIT, I do not see the values.

Does anyone have any ideas where I might be missing the value? Or if this is even possible?

Comment: I've found a hack for this, but it's a little unsavory. My downstream, Job Two, I've marked as a git job as well. That way vars get passed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done something similar with SVN using the [Paramaterized Trigger Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin). Just add GIT_COMMIT=GIT_COMMIT as a parameter on the first job.